# Access directly variant part of record from default property in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have the following record with a variant part:

```
RVector3 = packed record
  [...]
  case byte of
    0 : (X : Single; Y : Single; Z : Single);
    1 : (XY : RVector2);
    2 : (Element : array [0 .. 2] of Single);
end;
```

To have a faster access to the single elements, I wanted to add a default property.

```
function GetElement(Index : Integer) : Single;
procedure SetElement(Index : Integer; const Value : Single);
property Elements[index : Integer] : Single read GetElement write SetElement; default;
```

so I can do `myVector[Dim]` instead of `myVector.Element[Dim]`.
Now I was wondering if there is any way to omit the getter and setter methods and access the variable part directly. I know there is the possibility to do

```
TTestClass = class
  private
    FTestVector : RVector3;
  public
    property Test : single read FTestVector.Y write FTestVector.X;
end;
```

But is there is possibility to apply this to the record? Such as

```
property Elements[index : Integer] : Single read Element[Index] write Element[Index]; default;
```

which is unfortunately not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No,  it is not possible for a property getter or setter to access an element of an array directly. You need to use getter and setter functions. To optimise performance, if that matters to you, you can mark the getter and setter functions `inline`.